# Multiple cron jobs in a chef recipe

Tags: cron, chef-infra

I want to schedule 2 cron jobs using my chef recipe. Here are my entries

```
#Rotate the error logs
cron "logrotate every 5 minutes" do
  action :create
  user "root"
  minute "*/5"
  command "<my command>"
end

#Rotate the Quantico error logs
cron "logrotate every 5 minutes" do
  action :create
  user "root"
  minute "*/5"
  command "<my second command>"
end
```

When I run this chef recipe, I always see the only one entry in my `crontab -l` output. Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after going through the chef logs, I found this out. Cron creates the schedules based on the name you specify in the recipe and it doesn't create two separate jobs with the same name, instead, it updates them, which made sense (after looking at the logs). This is what I found in the logs:

```
[2019-05-31T15:27:02-07:00] INFO: cron[logrotate every 5 minutes] added crontab entry
.
.
[2019-05-31T15:27:03-07:00] INFO: cron[logrotate every 5 minutes] updated crontab entry
```

So, the only thing I had to do was rename the second cron job to make my life easier and get back my Friday evening.

```
#Rotate the error logs
cron "logrotate every 5 minutes" do
  action :create
  user "root"
  minute "*/5"
  command "<my command>"
end

#Rotate the Quantico error logs
cron "logrotate another file every 5 minutes" do
  action :create
  user "root"
  minute "*/5"
  command "<my second command>"
end
```

Comment: If we use `shell`, `home`, `environment` etc, it is created for each crontab `command`. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Not really sure about the use case, so can't help much. Maybe you can use the combination of all three in the name?